# javascript how to wrap iframe text in tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have an iframe where the user can type in text and press a button. When the button is pressed I want the highlighted text to be wrapped in a div tag as follows:

```
<div id="quote">text here</div>
```

How can I do this? I do want the div to have the id of "quote". Here is my code so far:

```
 <center><iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" ><?php echo $text;</iframe></center>
 <a class="buttonOnBar" id="btn14_quote" type="button" value="" onClick="javascript:iquote();" title="Quoteify"><img id="btnOnBarImg"src="img/icons/quote.png"></a>
```

Comment: Can you give some code as background?

Comment: yep there you go!

Comment: So you want to have an input field, a button, and a highlighted div. When the user presses the button, you want the input field to clear and the text to show up in the div?

Comment: no I have an iframe wiht any text typed into it, the user can highlight any part of that text and it is wrapped in a div with an id. That is what i want

Answer (score 0):

Here, I tested this in my browser. Sorry I couldn't use a snippet but their iframes don't allow accessing other iframed pages (even if they're null-domain pages). But make sure the style tag is in your head tag, it won't work otherwise (and then you won't see my ugly default styles `;-)`)

```
<iframe srcdoc='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteteur adipscing elit' id='rtf'></iframe>
<button id='make-div'>Make div</button>
<style>
.foo {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<script>
    onload = function() {
        var rtf = document.getElementById('rtf');
        rtf.contentDocument.designMode = 'on';
        document.getElementById('make-div').onclick = function() {
            var html = rtf.contentWindow.getSelection();
            var success = rtf.contentDocument.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<span class="foo">'+html+'</span>');
            if (!success) { alert('Functionality not supported by browser.'); }
        };
    }
</script>
```

Source for the main function used in this answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand